# Change the default encoding for saving files with Notepad++

Tags: encoding, notepad++

That's it . I want to open all the files in once (to make replacements). But notepad++ opens them all in ANSI and I have to go through each file and change the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Have you looked for any config files within its installation folder?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In Notepad++ 5.9 there is an option in Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/Default Directory to automatically convert ANSI files to UTF-8 without BOM on open

Comment: Finally a working solutin, thanks a lot. PS: From v6.1 it is called `Encoding` → `• UTF-8 without BOM` → `[x] Apply to opened ANSI files`

Comment: This isn't working as expected for me. When I open an ANSI file with this setting turned on, some characters don't convert correctly and I see a lot of 'x92', 'x94', etc black squares in place of certain characters.  When I turn the setting off and open the same file, it remains in the ANSI encoding and properly displays: ’ and ” characters (single-quote and double-quote).  Then I manually do: Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 and it converts correctly.  Is there some subtlety here that is causing the conversion not to work when the setting is turned on?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in the sense that if I do: `npp newfile.c` (where npp is just running n++ executable) in terminal - n++ asks me if it should create the non-existing file, I click on yes, and it's opened... as ANSI. But if I just click on "new file" in n++, it opens as UTF-8.

Answer (score 19):

Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/Default Directory -> UTF-8

Comment: this works only for new documents.. but if you opened an existing document it will not affect it

Comment: True that. If you're feeling adventurous, you could starting looking for the default encoding in the source and recompile it.

Comment: http://svn.tuxfamily.org/viewvc.cgi/notepadplus_repository/trunk/scintilla/win32/

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can change this in config.model.xml. I'm not sure if it is setting an unknown type as the default type, however, but it might be worth altering NewDocDefaultSettings

```
<GUIConfig name="NewDocDefaultSettings" format="0" encoding="0" lang="0" />
```

to

```
<GUIConfig name="NewDocDefaultSettings" format="0" encoding="4" lang="0" />
```

I think at worse case you might be able to record a Macro to automate this process.

Comment: Note that it should be renamed to (and overwrite) `config.xml`, the model file is just there as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I forgot to mention that!

Comment: The config.xml is actually found in `%userprofile%\%appdata%\Notepad++`. My entry looks like `<GUIConfig name="NewDocDefaultSettings" format="0" encoding="4" lang="0" codepage="850" openAnsiAsUTF8="no" />`

Answer (score 1):

Late but for new Users,i had faced a similar problem

**Step 1:**
**Settings -> Preferences -> New Document ->[Encodng] UTF-8 without BOM (check Apply to opened ANSI files)**

but any how it hadn't solved  mine , i searched out and  found that its a **bug!**

Notepad++ **v6.4.5** bug fixes:

1. Fix a crash issue while there's missing tag in functionList.xml. Fix
2. **UTF-8 (w/o BOM) detection bug.**

**Step 2:**
That's all have an update to >= **v6.4.5** and follow **Step 1**

Comment: True, step 1 alone did not work for me. Yet, just updated to V6.6.6 latest, Jun 2014 but still same issue. Even though I selected utf-8 without boom check opened ANSI files in settings-> preferences. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

look here to change default UTF8 settings for notepad ( new text documents ) - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/default-utf-8-encoding-for-new-notepad-documents/525f0ae7-121e-4eac-a6c2-cfe6b498712c

Comment: -1. Question is about *Notepad++*. This answer is about *Notepad*.