# Notepad++ always specified encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, notepad++

I am using notepad++ v6.7.4.
It seems notepad++ auto-detect encoding when opening a txt file. But I don not need such advanced feature.

My real question is :
Can I enforce notepad++ to open any txt files(new or pre-existing) in a specified encoding? For example, always ANSI or always UTF 8,...

I tried a lot to solve this question, but I couldn't. I can't stop notepad++ to auto-detect encoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090845/change-the-default-encoding-for-notepad

Comment: Thanks, I have read the post and tried before asking here. I tried but not worked.  Note that this is about notepad++ v6.7.4. If you know the correct method to stop auto-detection.. then please try it with v6.7.4.  I will be very appreciated if you teach me!

Answer (score 0):

there is a setting under Settings, Preferences..., Select Misc and then there is a checkbox "Autodetect character encoding" in the lower left part.

Did you try unchecking that setting?

Comment: So far I did exactly :
1) download v6.7.4 in portable zip edition, extract it.
2) double click notepad++.exe
3) settings - preferences - new document - check ANSI in Encoding
4) settings - preferences - MISC. - uncheck Autodetect character encoding
5) close settings and close notepad++.exe, restart notepad++.exe
6) press Encoding in menubar - confirm 'Encode in Ansi' is checked
7) drag and drop test.txt to the workspace of notepad++
Then I press Encoding in menubar, then I see 'Encode in UTF-8' is checked.

Comment: Yes, you are right, regardless of "autodetect encoding" is checked or not, the file encoding is set to the encoding the file was saved in. I can observe this behaviour in v.6.7.3, too.

Comment: You mean there is no way to directly open "every txt file in ANSI" in notepad++ ? Must I change encoding, after loading the file ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the setting solved your problem and I am also surprised that it does not work. You could ask for help on their forum or file a bugreport there.